# Sublime avoid cursor follow up to next line

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sublimetext3

After I use

`Ctrl + C` for any line and `Ctrl + V`(on the next line)

after paste, it simply moves the cursor to next line.

How to avoid this ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you selecting a line end in the text you copy (Ctrl+C)?

Comment: @duncan I have made the edit

Comment: Your edit is no more comprehensive and, if anything, is less comprehensible than before. Please describe: **exactly** what you are doing :: what exactly is happening :: what exactly you want to have happen instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you select only the required portion of the text and copy it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and paste using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, then only the selected portion will be copied and no new line will be added unless you select new line also.